# firebase cloud messaging not getting registered

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My unique Id is generated and gets saved in my MYSQL Database… but when I send the the notification thro php script , I get a 500 error stating cannot find the resource u are looking for the below line

$firebase->set($uniqueid.’/msg’, $msg);

I check my google firebase console , and can’t seem to find the registered id.
Also when I send a message from the console using User Segment , the notification got delivered ,
but when I use ‘Single Device’ giving the unique generated no , the notification fails..
help plz…
Thanks

Comment: Could you include the code that you are using to retrieve the IID Token (unique ID)?

Comment: Firebase firebase = new Firebase(com.twiginc.twig.getset.Constants.FIREBASE_APP);
Firebase newFirebase = firebase.push();
Map<String, String> val = new HashMap<>();
val.put("msg", "none");
newFirebase.setValue(val);

 //Getting the unique id generated at firebase
String uniqueId = newFirebase.getKey();

Comment: :) I meant in the question, however it does not seem like you are using the correct libraries to generate the FCM token. Could you add your dependencies to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorials for me it helps do you have 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiKCEa5_Cs8

Comment: I have seen that, its gud but docent help